# How to configure a dockerfile and docker-compose for Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im absolutely new in Docker and Jenkins as well. I have a question about the configuration of Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file. I tried to use the easiest configuration to be able to set-up these files correctly. Building and pushing is done correctly, but the jenkins application is not running on my localhost (127.0.0.1).

If I understand it correctly, now it should default running on port 50000 (ARG agent_port=50000 in jenkins "official" Dockerfile). I tried to use 50000, 8080 and 80 as well, nothing is working. Do you have any advice, please? Im using these files: https://github.com/fdolsky321/Jenkins_Docker

The second question is, whats the best way to handle the crashes of the container. Lets say, that if the container crashes, I want to recreate a new container with the same settings. Is the best way just to create a new shell file like "crash.sh" and provide there the information, that I want to create new container with the same settings? Like is mentioned in here: https://blog.codeship.com/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy/

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Which docker are you using? On which OS?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give provide this very important information. Windows 10 Pro, x64

Comment: What docker version? What is the docker guest? HyperV with docker for Windows? VirtualBox with dockerm-machine?

Comment: PS C:\Users\admin> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:57:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:59:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

Comment: I'm using HyperV with docker for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

**docker-compose for Jenkins**

[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/JinnaBalu/dev-ops/blob/master/docker-jenkins/jenkins.yml)

```
version: '2'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    # uncomment for docker in docker
    privileged: true
    volumes:
        # enable persistent volume (warning: make sure that the local jenkins_home folder is created)
        - /var/wisestep/data/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
        # mount docker sock and binary for docker in docker (only works on linux)
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

Replace the port 8080, 50000 as you need in your host.

**To recreate a new container with the same settings**

The volumne mounted jenkins_home, is the placewhere you store all your jobs and settings etc..

Take the backup of the mounted volume jenkins_home on creating every job  or the way you want.
Whenever there is any crash, run the Jenkins with the same docker-compose file and replace the jenkins_home folder with the backup.

**Rerun/restart jenkins again**

List the container

```
docker ps -a
```

Restart container

```
docker restart <Required_Container_ID_To_Restart>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been using a docker-compose.yml that looks like the following:

```
version: '3.2'

volumes:
  jenkins-home:

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins-docker
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    container_name: jenkins-docker
```

My image is a locally built Jenkins image, based off of jenkins/jenkins:lts, that adds in some other components like docker itself, and I'm mounting the docker socket to allow me to run commands on the docker host. This may not be needed for your use case. The important parts for you are the ports being published, which for me is only 8080, and the volume for /var/jenkins_home to preserve the Jenkins configuration between image updates.

To recover from errors, I have `restart: unless-stopped` inside the docker-compose.yml to configure the container to automatically restart. If you're running this in swarm mode, that would be automatic.

I typically avoid defining a container name, but in this scenario, there will only ever be one jenkins-docker container, and I like to be able to view the logs with `docker logs jenkins-docker` to gather things like the initial administrator login token.

My Dockerfile and other dependencies for this image are available at: https://github.com/bmitch3020/jenkins-docker

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.So now its working, BUT,if I use this command: <docker run --rm $DOCKER_HUB_USER/jenkins:test>,its running on default ports 8080/tcp, 50000/tcp. But I specified in my docker-compose file another port (I tried to use the port 49003 for this time, which is changed in docker-compose.yml).So then I need to specify the ports like this: <docker run --rm -p 49003:8080 $DOCKER_HUB_USER/jenkins:test>. And then, if I want to run this on port 49003, what does mean the second port 8080?Because if I use 49003:49003, it doesnt work. Any advice, please?But you helped me so much!!

Comment: I hope, that ports should be specified in docker-compose.yml, not in Dockerfile, right? It just seems, that it ignore the settings in compose file.

Comment: The docker-compose.yml file is used by `docker-compose`, calling `docker run` completely ignores this file.

Comment: Thank you, BMitch, so how should I create the container by using the docker-compose? I builded it, I pushed it to my Docker hub and then I want to run that on ports specified in docker-compose. How should I do that, please?

Answer (score 0):

> HyperV with docker for Windows.

In that case, you must be sure you port-forward any published port (like 5000).

Open HyperV manager, and right-click on the machine defined there: you will be able to add port-forwarding rules in order for localhost:5000 to access your VM:5000.

Comment: Is it necessarily? Because this should be fine, when I tried to publish it manually, it worked on port 49001 for example...

Comment: @FrantisekDolsky OK (I didn't get that from your question). Try at least a docker ps -a, to see what container is running, and which port are published. Then try to access them using the docker machine ip instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: @FrantisekDolsky They look OK (but I don't have access to an environment to test them). Do you see the containers running with `docker ps -a`?